# Errors in AMP Pages

Tags: amp-html

We are getting following error messages for our AMP pages in Google Webmaster Console:

```
The tag 'div' is disallowed.
The tag 'ul' is disallowed.
The tag 'h2' is disallowed.
The tag 'a' is disallowed.
The tag 'li' is disallowed.
```

However, the following page states that all the above tags are allowed in AMP pages:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-tag-addendum.md

Can anyone please let me know what might be the issue here.

Comment: Have you checked if the tags are disallowed where they are located? E.g. you may have a `div` inside another tag where it is not allowed in AMP.

Comment: @jeffreypriebe Thank you for your response. Can you please provide a link to where AMPProject says this is the case. I am not able to locate this in the documentation.

Comment: I have none, I'm new to AMP as well and am speculating as to a possible source of issues worth checking (hence a comment not an answer).

Comment: Thank you for your response @jeffreypriebe. I suspect that might be the case. However, i have gone through the docs multiple times and not able to find anything specific.

Comment: If you would like help here, please provide the URL. It's difficult to imaging every possible reason why you might see these error messages.